# Алгоритмическое решение задачи на удаление повторяющихся элементов в одномерном массиве

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем здравствуйте! Вот формулировка задачи (предполагается, что её нужно решить на Python):
В одномерном массиве удалить (алгоритмически) повторные вхождения элементов. Нельзя использовать del, remove, pop. Срезы можно использовать только 1 раз.
Я решила эту задачу, но не алгоритмическим способом:

```
n = int(input('Enter the size: '))
array = []
for i in range(n):
    array.append(int(input('Enter an element: ')))
length = len(array)
array.append(array[0])
for i in range(1,length):
    if array[i] not in array[:i]:
        array.append(array[i])
array = array[length:]
print(array)
```

Не могли бы вы натолкнуть меня на мысль, какой алгоритм предполагается использовать для решения данной задачи?
P.S: Ещё у меня есть небольшая просьба: основываясь на формулировке задачи, могли бы вы подсказать, где можно порешать подобные? Пробовала искать на LeetCode, GeeksforGeeks, Codeforces, Codewars и т.д., однако там подобного не нашла. Возможно, это именно эта задача была придумана преподавателями кафедры в университете, в котором я обучаюсь. К сожалению, нам не дают решать дополнительные задания. Мне не хватает практики, поэтому обращаюсь сюда. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие ресурсы использовать, чтобы отточить навык решения задач. Буду благодарна)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ну, скажем, так: сортировка, затем копирование в выходной массив только оригинальных значений (т.е. если равно предыдущему - пропустить). PS. В задании не сказано, должна ли операция быть устойчивой.

Comment: А что означает "алгоритмически" и " не алгоритмическим способом"? Все программы, что вы пишете, реализуют некий алгоритм

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за ответ! Именно этот алгоритм я держала в голове, но думала, что есть ещё решение, которое я упускаю..

Comment: ещё вариант - использование словаря (dictionary). Нет в словаре - добавляем в него и  в выходной массив

Comment: @MBo, это одна из задач, которую нам дали на контрольной по программированию (я не успела её реализовать за отведённое время, которое, к сожалению, нам сократили). Думаю, предполагалось, что нельзя использовать возможности языка Python. Так бы я, конечно, быстро её решила((

Comment: @MBo поскольку нужно только присутствие, а не счётчик, то множество, а не словарь, конечно

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, точно.

Comment: `list(collections.Counter(array).keys())`

Comment: @MBo, насколько я поняла, нельзя использовать дополнительную память. Я решила её другим способом: отсортировала массив (как предложил Akina), добавила в его конец те элементы, что не равны соседним в уже отсортированном массиве, а затем взяла срез от n-го элемента (где n - это размер массива) до самого конца. Думаю, есть решение и получше, но это, кажется, удовлетворяет условию.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, именно так нам и не разрешают делать(( Нужно решить алгоритмически, что бы это ни значило..

Comment: Взятие среза - линейная дополнительная память.

Comment: У вас, в целом, направление правильное. Реализация слишком расточительная. :)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо за комментарий! А можете подсказать, в каком направлении двигаться, чтобы обойти эту расточительную реализацию? Просто я придерживалась условия, которое дали в университете, но если можно и без среза обойтись, то хотелось бы узнать логику такой реализации)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, такое решение понравится преподвателю. Сперва упорядочиваем массив (честно говоря [сортировка в Питоне](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) может потребовать линейной дополнительной памяти, притворюсь что никто этого не знает). Затем запускаем классический алгоритм удаления дупликатов: по массиву бегут два указателя - `i` и `j`. `i` бежит без остановок, `j` задерживается на единицу на каждой паре равных элементов. Элементы копируются из `i` в `j`.
Когда цикл закончился, обрезаем хвост, присваивая пустой список.

```
n = int(input('Enter the size: '))
array = [int(input('Enter an element: ')) for _ in range(n)]
array.sort()
i = j = 1
for i in range(1, len(array)):
    if array[i] != array[i - 1]:
        array[j] = array[i]
        j += 1
array[j:] = []
print(array)
```

P.S. Очень "алгоритмически" как мне кажется. :) И срез используется один раз. Я в комментарии сказал что взятие среза - дополнительная память. Приврал слегка. Не всегда это так. Если срез слева от присваивания, дополнительная память не будет использоваться.

P.P.S. Если преподавателя не слушать, то каноническое решение такое:

```
n = int(input('Enter the size: '))
array = [int(input('Enter an element: ')) for _ in range(n)]
array = list(set(array))
print(array)
```

Сложность этого решения и по времени и по памяти - `O(N)`.

Решение с сортировкой потребует `O(NlogN)` времени (`N` - длина исходного массива) и, скорее всего, `O(N)` дополнительной памяти при сортировке. Но сортировку можно заменить на другую, которая не использует дополнительную память.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Вы помогаете отчаявшимся студентам становиться лучше! :)

Comment: Я бы ещё отметил, что сортировка работает медленней, чем вариант с хешсетом.

Comment: @tym32167, вы правы. Я опустил этот момент, так как уровень вопроса явно не предполагает знакомства TC со сложностью алгоритмов.

Comment: Ответы пишутся не только для автора вопроса. Сама задача нахождения уникальных элементов массива встречается довольно часто. Потому, мне кажется, будет полезно упомянуть про скорость работы для будущих читателей вашего ответа.

Comment: @tym32167, спасибо. Добавил сложности.

Comment: Возможно, стоит ещё упомянуть почему сложность получается линейная :)(хотя бы ссылкой на ресурс какой-нибудь, где это объясняется). Но мб это уже придирка, up to you.